# iOS : Initialization of UIImage

Tags: objective-c, uiimage, ios5

Which call is correct ? Seems that both calls have same result.

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"image" ofType:@"png"]];
```

or

```
UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"image" ofType:@"png"]];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First in correct, as imageWithContentsOfFile is a class convenience method(Class method).

Answer (score -3):

The easiest way to initialize a UIImage is...

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed: @"image.png"];
```

Comment: `UIImage imageNamed` has memory issues, thus we should avoid it.

Comment: this is not answer of question?

Comment: @rishi No, just because it compiles doesn't necessarily mean it works.

Comment: @rishi Fair enough.  I was just trying to help OP achieve the same objective in an easier manner.